terraform: Escaping double quotes from JSON to be passed to jsondecode()
I have a json file that im passing to jsondecode() in terraform and I need to remove quotes from array elements ...as the terraform data structure im creating needs them unquoted
This is my example source JSON file
  {
    "name"                  : "something",
    "project"               : "project1",
    "events" : [
      "module.test.some_value",
      "module.test.some_other_value"
    ]
  }

when I run this through jsondecode() The values in the "events" array above still retain the double quotes...but I need them to be removed , this is what it looks like after jsondecode()
  {
    name    = "something",
    project = "project1",
    events  = [
      "module.test.some_value",
      "module.test.some_other_value"
    ]
  }

but I need the "events" part to look like this... (i.e. no quotes)
    events  = [
      module.test.some_value,
      module.test.some_other_value
    ]
  

I have tried \ , \\ , and \\\ as escaping methods i.e
i.e
    "events" : [
      \\"module.test.some_value\\",
      \\"module.test.some_other_value\\"
    ]

but terraform plan complains each time with
│ Call to function "jsondecode" failed: invalid character '\' looking for
│ beginning of value.
Does anyone know the best way for me to escape these quotes so that they dont appear on the rendered output of jsondecode()
Any help would be greatly appreciated

JSON schema does not support variables/expression types like those, and neither does HCL if I recall correctly. This is likely not possible with the direct JSON-->HCL decoding and encoding that TF performs with go-cty. You would probably need a wrapper.


Write your file as a template, and pass it to the templatefile func (docs here)

pass the resulting string to jsonencode.


Template:
  {
    "name"                  : "something",
    "project"               : "project1",
    "events" : [
%{ for value in values ~}
      "${value}",
%{ endfor ~}
    ]
  }

HCL:
locals {
  valorised_template = templatefile("mytemplatefile.tftpl", {
    values: [module.test.some_value, module.test.some_other_value]
  })
  decoded_object = jsondecode(local.valorised_template)
}


I think what you are meaning to ask is how to treat parts of a JSON document as if they are Terraform expressions. That is not actually directly possible because jsondecode only implements JSON parsing and decoding, not Terraform expression evaluation.
However, you could explicitly transform the jsondecode result yourself using additional logic in your module.
Since this won't actually be evaluating the expressions with Terraform I would suggest using simple symbolic keys instead to avoid implying that this is more general than it actually is:
  {
    "name"                  : "something",
    "project"               : "project1",
    "event_attributes" : [
      "some_value",
      "some_other_value"
    ]
  }

If you pass this to jsondecode then, similar to your question, you'll get literal string values in event_attributes:
  {
    name    = "something",
    project = "project1",
    event_attributes = [
      "some_value",
      "some_other_value"
    ]
  }

You can then use another expression to replace event_attributes with events, like this:
locals {
  raw_object = jsondecode(file("${path.module}/example.json"))
  object = {
    name    = local.raw_object.name
    project = local.raw_object.project
    events = [
      for attr_name in local.raw_object.event_attributes :
      module.test[attr_name]
    ]
  }
}

The events attribute is populated using a for expression, which evaluates module.test[attr_name] for each value in event_attributes, and so will take the value of the attribute whose name is in attr_name.
You can then use local.object elsewhere in your module to make use of the transformed result.
